# Get single data from table that has multiple values

Tags: mysql

I have to join my tables from my database, but it has multiple data (repeating data), this is my query:

```
select ruper from bsl_ruang b join mr_ranap_dokter d on (b.noregis=d.noregis) where d.dokter = '11111'
```

and the result like this;

```
ruper
1111
1111
2222
2233
2233
3333
3333
3333
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
ruper
1111
2222
2233
3333
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the DISTINCT keyword.

```
select DISTINCT ruper from bsl_ruang b join mr_ranap_dokter d on (b.noregis=d.noregis) where d.dokter = '11111'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct ruper
from bsl_ruang b join
     mr_ranap_dokter d
     on (b.noregis=d.noregis)
where d.dokter = '11111';
```